# Is it smart to "clean out" my Python environment?

Tags: python, dependencies, dependency-management

I am a Python beginner and am running Python on the Mac. I started to read up on pipenv and virtualenv and checked how my system was configured. Turns out that i have a Godzillian amount of packages installed under my systems python environment. AFAIU from pipenv and virtualenv this is exactly what you don't want to happen.

So now i am looking to correct this and apply best practices by hosting all dependencies in project folders but before to do this my question: Is it smart to "clean out" the system environment and host everything in project folders? Or should i keep the system environment as is it and just start adding dependencies into newly created project folders? I don't care about disk space, i do care about dependency conflicts.

Comment: There could be cases you want to write quick scripts and you don't want to create a completely new environment for that. Instead use an existing one. In that case, your existing system environment would be useful.
My suggestion would be leave your system env as it is and proceed creating new envs.

Comment: The system python belongs to the system. Fiddling with it means fiddling with your system. Do not do this unless you know precisely what you are doing.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: Understood. But what if this is not a clean system? What if i have been sudo pip installing a bunch of stuff already and that all sits in my system python environment? Should i not clean this out to avoid issues?

Comment: Unless you know exactly which parts are *only* there due to your own actions, do not touch it. If you remove anything that some system service depends on, you will have a hard time fixing this.

Answer (score 1):

You should absolutely do not want to clear out your system environment. The system version of python will be used by your operating system and if you damage it, who knows what havoc you'll cause.

Ideally, you want to leave your system's version of python alone, and then have your own, separate version of python which you actually use for development, where you control the packages etc.

A popular way to install a version of python and manage packages is to use anaconda: https://www.anaconda.com/ , so I'd suggest looking into that.